# Span not updated during execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm showing the progress of code that takes quite long to finish, by printing a message every time a new calculation starts. The message is printed to a span element. However, this only works in Firefox. In Chrome, the span only updates when all calculations have finished.

I tried printing the message to a div or p element, didn't work. I tried executing the code with setTimeout, to allow the browser to update, this didn't work either. I tried adding "style="position: relative"" to the span element, didn't help.

I tried running the code in Chrome incognito mode, didn't work.

javascript:

```
// Export teachers
function export_teachers (){

    // Update progress span
    $("#span_progress_export").html("Export teachers");

    [...]

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    // Data confirmed for export
    $(document).on("click","#button_confirm_timetable", function() {
        export_teachers();
        export_classgroups();
        export_classrooms();
    });

});
```

html:

```
<button id="button_confirm_timetable">confirm timetable</button> 
<span id="span_confirm_status"></span>
<br><br><span id="span_progress_export">Start export</span>
```

The span should update every time a new calculation finishes. I can see the span text updating in the source code in the console, but not on the web page. In Firefox, everything is working as it should be.

Comment: Can you post a running version of your code (SO snippet, Codepen, etc.) with the full `export...` functions? This seems like it may be a timing issue, but it's hard to be sure without the entire code.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Posting the full code is difficult, because the slow part is defined by multiple database connections (which happen asynchronously by the way, using ajax, could this be the problem?). I tried to construct a minimal running version of my code, but I don't really see how without connecting to the database. However, if this is necessary, I can try harder of course ;).

Comment: The AJAX calls could be the problem. Firefox may handle the order that they are made in/resolve in differently than Chrome. What is likely happening is that all three calls are made in quick succession and the HTML updates each time, but too quickly for you to see it happen. Try [throttling your connection with the dev tools](https://css-tricks.com/throttling-the-network/) and then making the calls. That may shed some light on your issue

Comment: Thank you, throttling looks like a very useful function! I tried it, but no success: the span message doesn't change until the code has finished.

Quite some time elapses between the three calls (multiple seconds), so the changes in span message would definitely be visible. I can see the span message changing in the console, but not on the screen...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**html**

```
<button id="button_confirm_timetable">confirm timetable</button> 
<span id="span_confirm_status"></span><br><br>
<span id="span_progress_export">Start export</span>
```

**jquery**

```
// Export teachers
function export_teachers (){
   // Update progress span
   $("#span_progress_export").html("Export teachers");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#button_confirm_timetable").click(function() {
      export_teachers();
 });
});
```

working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cruz888/pmy7ufta/2/

Comment: Thank you for your response!

You added the "$(document).ready"? Because this is already present in my code, I'm sorry, I forgot to add this (I will edit my question).

So this doesn't solve my issue, but thanks!

Comment: And changed the way in which the click event is triggered? I just tried this, didn't help unfortunately...